# how to format thermal printer in android using byte?

Tags: android, qr-code

I want to know how the byte code work in thermal printer

```
            tcmd = new byte[7];
            tcmd[0] = 0x1B;
            tcmd[1] = 0x5A;
            tcmd[2] = 0x00;
            tcmd[3] = 0x02;
            tcmd[4] = 0x07;
            tcmd[5] = 0x17;
            tcmd[6] = 0x00;
            String content = "SDK 2D-Code print test.";
            wfComm.sndByte(tcmd);
            wfComm.sendMsg(content, "GBK");
```

this code send the data to printer and the printer print the qr code that has the string , but if i send this without the byte array the printer simply print the string.
I want to  understand the byte code if you can give me the documentation in which show that how this byte work

[Check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHuT3.png)

Answer (score 0):

> The code is tested and verified..it will convert qr code to byte and print it in paper.just create utils class as described below and call this method..

byte[] command = Utils.decodeBitmap(bitmap);
                    mService.write(command);

```
public class Utils {
// UNICODE 0x23 = #
public static final byte[] UNICODE_TEXT = new byte[] {0x23, 0x23, 0x23,
        0x23, 0x23, 0x23,0x23, 0x23, 0x23,0x23, 0x23, 0x23,0x23, 0x23, 0x23,
        0x23, 0x23, 0x23,0x23, 0x23, 0x23,0x23, 0x23, 0x23,0x23, 0x23, 0x23,
        0x23, 0x23, 0x23};

private static String hexStr = "0123456789ABCDEF";
private static String[] binaryArray = { "0000", "0001", "0010", "0011",
        "0100", "0101", "0110", "0111", "1000", "1001", "1010", "1011",
        "1100", "1101", "1110", "1111" };

public static byte[] decodeBitmap(Bitmap bmp){
    int bmpWidth = bmp.getWidth();
    int bmpHeight = bmp.getHeight();

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); //binaryString list
    StringBuffer sb;


    int bitLen = bmpWidth / 8;
    int zeroCount = bmpWidth % 8;

    String zeroStr = "";
    if (zeroCount > 0) {
        bitLen = bmpWidth / 8 + 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < (8 - zeroCount); i++) {
            zeroStr = zeroStr + "0";
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < bmpHeight; i++) {
        sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int j = 0; j < bmpWidth; j++) {
            int color = bmp.getPixel(j, i);

            int r = (color >> 16) & 0xff;
            int g = (color >> 8) & 0xff;
            int b = color & 0xff;

            // if color close to white，bit='0', else bit='1'
            if (r > 160 && g > 160 && b > 160)
                sb.append("0");
            else
                sb.append("1");
        }
        if (zeroCount > 0) {
            sb.append(zeroStr);
        }
        list.add(sb.toString());
    }

    List<String> bmpHexList = binaryListToHexStringList(list);
    String commandHexString = "1D763000";
    String widthHexString = Integer
            .toHexString(bmpWidth % 8 == 0 ? bmpWidth / 8
                    : (bmpWidth / 8 + 1) );
    if (widthHexString.length() > 2) {
        Log.e("decodeBitmap error", " width is too large");
        return null;
    } else if (widthHexString.length() == 1) {
        widthHexString = "0" + widthHexString;
    }
    widthHexString = widthHexString + "00";

    String heightHexString = Integer.toHexString(bmpHeight);
    if (heightHexString.length() > 2) {
        Log.e("decodeBitmap error", " height is too large");
        return null;
    }
    else if (heightHexString.length() == 1) {
        heightHexString = "0" + heightHexString;
    }
    heightHexString = heightHexString + "00";

    List<String> commandList = new ArrayList<String>();
    commandList.add(commandHexString+widthHexString+heightHexString);
    commandList.addAll(bmpHexList);

    return hexList2Byte(commandList);
}

public static List<String> binaryListToHexStringList(List<String> list) {
    List<String> hexList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String binaryStr : list) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < binaryStr.length(); i += 8) {
            String str = binaryStr.substring(i, i + 8);

            String hexString = myBinaryStrToHexString(str);
            sb.append(hexString);
        }
        hexList.add(sb.toString());
    }
    return hexList;

}

public static String myBinaryStrToHexString(String binaryStr) {
    String hex = "";
    String f4 = binaryStr.substring(0, 4);
    String b4 = binaryStr.substring(4, 8);
    for (int i = 0; i < binaryArray.length; i++) {
        if (f4.equals(binaryArray[i]))
            hex += hexStr.substring(i, i + 1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < binaryArray.length; i++) {
        if (b4.equals(binaryArray[i]))
            hex += hexStr.substring(i, i + 1);
    }

    return hex;
}

public static byte[] hexList2Byte(List<String> list) {
    List<byte[]> commandList = new ArrayList<byte[]>();

    for (String hexStr : list) {
        commandList.add(hexStringToBytes(hexStr));
    }
    byte[] bytes = sysCopy(commandList);
    return bytes;
}

public static byte[] hexStringToBytes(String hexString) {
    if (hexString == null || hexString.equals("")) {
        return null;
    }
    hexString = hexString.toUpperCase();
    int length = hexString.length() / 2;
    char[] hexChars = hexString.toCharArray();
    byte[] d = new byte[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        int pos = i * 2;
        d[i] = (byte) (charToByte(hexChars[pos]) << 4 | charToByte(hexChars[pos + 1]));
    }
    return d;
}

public static byte[] sysCopy(List<byte[]> srcArrays) {
    int len = 0;
    for (byte[] srcArray : srcArrays) {
        len += srcArray.length;
    }
    byte[] destArray = new byte[len];
    int destLen = 0;
    for (byte[] srcArray : srcArrays) {
        System.arraycopy(srcArray, 0, destArray, destLen, srcArray.length);
        destLen += srcArray.length;
    }
    return destArray;
}

private static byte charToByte(char c) {
    return (byte) "0123456789ABCDEF".indexOf(c);
}}
```